# Ruby on Rails how to add a 'require' statement so it is available to all models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

we have a complex web application running on rails 4.0.13

There is a core application and then optional extensions available as gems.  A common function for both core and extensions is to output to .csv format.  Often we turn an array to csv using the '.to_csv' using the csv.rb file and implemented by adding the line "require 'csv'"

To which file can I add the "require 'csv'" so it is available to all models, be they in the core application, or in extensions (gems)?

I want to do it the standard way if there is one

Comment: You can put `require 'csv'` in config/application.rb

Comment: or in an initializer

Answer (score 1):

You have to add one initializer for it.

```
# config/initializers/csv.rb

require 'csv'
```

After adding this file, please restart your server.